# Notepad ++ Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

### Notepad ++ Replacing Multiple Words

Okay so heres what i need to know, currently i am searching multiple words at once, heres some sample data

```
(\bACCESS\b)|(\bAccs\b)|(\bALLEY\b)|(\bAlly\b)|(\bALLEYWAY\b)
```

What i want to do is add a ":" to the end of every word that is found. Like this

```
41 dwadadad Rd:
93 awdawdadawd Terrace:
4/100 awdadawdwad St:
32 awdawdawdawd Ave:
59 awdawdawd Street: Ferny Grove
```

Is there a regular expression for only getting the end of the matched word?

Comment: The text you supplied cannot be matched with your regex. What is the valid test case? `41 dwadadad Accs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change your regex to:

```
((\bACCESS\b)|(\bAccs\b)|(\bALLEY\b)|(\bAlly\b)|(\bALLEYWAY\b))
```

And then replace with: `\1:`

Comment: Thank you :), Worked, Just a question so i can understand im guessing \1 is the end of the word?

Comment: This regex is not clean nor optimal. Read about the backreference in my answer. I used `$0` - there is NO need in capture groups. And provided a link to the regular-expressions.info reference.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an alternation list with just two word boundaries  - at the start and end of the pattern, and just one group:

```
\b(?:Rd|Terrace|St|Ave|Street)\b
```

And replace with `$0:` (where `$0` [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) references the whole match, if the pattern matched `Rd`, the `Rd` will be inserted in the resulting string).

Note that we can use 2 `\b` only becayse they enclose the alternation non-capturing group `(?:...)`, and are thus applied to each alternative. It shortens the regex and speeds it up.

[image]